# Rules of concatenation

Tags: formal-languages

I am studying for an exam, and have stumbled across the following statement which is marked as false:
abab ∈ {a, b}{a, b}

My textbook defines concatenation as: "joining two input lists or strings of length m and n into one of length m+n by putting elements of the second list or string after those of the first."

How is this example false/not an example of proper concatenation? To me it seems perfectly legal.

[For clarity, here is the information we are given to define concatenation/the notation used.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CpqS.jpg)
[+ Continued explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJP3F.jpg)

Comment: Are you asking about sets, or about [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)?

Comment: might be better at another stack exchange site?

Comment: What is 'abab' supposed to be?  I asssume is is the string of a folllowed by b followed by a followed by b.  What is $\{a,b\}\{a,b\}$.  I'm actually not sure what to a assume.  Is it the set of concatentions of length 2?  Is it the same thing as 'abab'?  Is it something else.  $\in$ implies it is a set but I've never seen a set written as $\{a,b\}\{a,b\}$ and don't see how one would interpret that.

Comment: Notice a concatentation of *languages* is different then a concation of strings or input lists for strings.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I have understood your definition, given two sets of strings $S$, $T$ we have
$$ST := \{ st \mid s \in S, t \in T\}.$$
Note that $st$ denotes concatenation of the strings $s$ and $t$. For instance, if $s=apple$ and $t=pie$, $st=applepie$.
In particular, $\{a,b\}\{a,b\}=\{aa,ab,ba,bb\}$. You cannot get a string of length $4$ from two strings of length $1$.

Comment: That does not fit the definition given. Note yours has $n\times m$ elements.  Not $n+m$.  I thin the actual definition would be $ST=\{d_i|$ where if $i\le n$ then $d_i = $ then $i$th element of $S$ and other wise $d_i=$ then $i-n$th element of $T$.  And note $S,T$ are not sets of strings, but input list for a single string itself.  i.e S = {a,p,p,l,e} $equiv$ apple.  What you describe is a concetenation of *languages* but $\{a,b\}$ is not a language.

Comment: I think you might have interpreted my answer in the wrong way: I do get length $m+n$ when concatenating strings of length $m$ and $n$. I described a concatenation of sets of strings.

Comment: Right. But the definition described in the OP is *not* a concatenation of a set of strings.   At any event, you are correct.  If {a,b}{a,b} is a concatenation of strings is is {aa,ab,ba,bb}.  If {a,b}{a,b} is a concatentation of input lists then {a,b}{a,b } = {a,b,a,b}=abab.  In either event abab $\not \in$ {aa,ab,ba,bb} and abab $\not \in$ abab.

Answer (score 0):

The definition says that if $S = \{a,b,c,d\}$ and $T=\{a,b,x,y\}$ then $ST:= abcdabxy$.

Or if $s = "rubbie", t="duckie"$ then $st = rubbieduckie$.

So $abab = \{a,b\}\{a,b\}$.

So $abab \in \{a,b\}\{a,b\}$ is false.  $\{a,b\}\{a,b\}$ is not a set or a list and $abab = \{a,b\}\{a,b\}$ is not an element $abab = \{a,b\}\{a,b\}$.

It is NOT the case that $abab \in abab$.

Comment: This is probably not what the definition ought to mean. (As you state it, it's not even well-defined, since $\{a,b,c,d\}$ and $\{b,a,d,c\}$ are the same set, but $abcdabxy$ and $badcabxy$ are not the same string.)

Comment: "list" not set.  Finite and of ordered.  So as lists $\{a,b,c,d\} \ne \{b,a,d,c\}$ and also $\{a,a\}$ is an acceptable list but not an acceptable set.  I'm not sure it's the best definition but I've seen worse.  I don't know what $\{a,b\}\{a,b\}$ is supposed to be but in light of the definition (which whether it ought to exist or not, nonetheless *is* the definition the OP provided), I assume it to mean $\{a,b\}\{a,b\} = abab$. i.e. a concatenation.  In which case the symbol does not apply.